# Change the verbosity of wpa_supplicant when managed by network-manager/dbus

Tags: wireless, networking

`wpa_supplicant` writes to `/var/log/syslog`. You can run it with option `-d` or `-dd` to add verbosity, but it is started automatically by `network-manager`/`dbus` so you don't get to enter your own options. How do you increase verbosity anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For older versions of network-manager (<0.9), you can edit

```
/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/fi.epitest.hostap.WPASupplicant.service
```

In 0.9, the file has changed to `fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.service`, so you now have to edit

```
/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.service
```

The file should look like this:

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1
Exec=/sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /var/run/wpa_supplicant
User=root
```

And you can add your options in the `Exec` line. To make `network-manager` restart `wpa_supplicant`, run

```
ps aux | grep wpa
```

and kill the `wpa_supplicant` process

```
kill -9 12345
```

It will start back up automatically.